# Why isn't my didEndSelector in my NSAlert being called?

Tags: objective-c, macos, modal-dialog, switch-statement, nsalert

I can't figure out why my didEndSelector isn't being called. Any ideas?

```
 - (void) showMonitorAlertIfNeeded {

    if (! self.monitorAlert && [self isHideMonitorAlert]) {

        self.monitorAlert = [MMAlertController monitorAlert];

        [[self.monitorAlert window] setTitle: [self applicationName]];

        [self.monitorAlert beginSheetModalForWindow: [NSApp keyWindow] 
                                    modalDelegate: self 
                                   didEndSelector: @selector(monitorAlertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
                                      contextInfo: nil];


        [[self.monitorAlert window] setLevel: NSScreenSaverWindowLevel];

    }
}


- (void) monitorAlertDidEnd: (NSAlert *) alert returnCode: (NSInteger) code contextInfo: (id) contextInfo {

    switch (code) {
        case NSAlertFirstButtonReturn:{
        }
            NSLog(@"FIRST BUTTON PRESSED");
            break;

        case NSAlertSecondButtonReturn:{ // don't show again.
            NSLog(@"SECOND BUTTON PRESSED");
            [[NSApp delegate]setIsHideMonitorAlert:NO];
        }

        break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried an NSLog outside the switch?

Comment: Hmm, just tried it actually. It's being called, any idea why my switch statements aren't being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert this line just before the switch:

```
NSLog(@"code: %ld", code);
```

Comment: The first button pressed and second button pressed don't get logged. If I put it outside of the switch statement it does.

Comment: What I meant to know was if you logged the value of the code outside the switch.

Comment: Yes, anything in showMonitorAlertIfNeeded gets logged, anything outside of the switch(code){} gets logged in monitorAlertDidEnd

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, that's because we were logging %@ and not %d, I'm gonna try and create a switch with the specific numbers instead.

Comment: In my application I have a similar callback function for my NSAlert, the only diference I can see is that instead of code my parameter is called returnCode, but I don't it should make a diference.

Answer (score 3):

If `[MMAlertController monitorAlert]` returns an `NSAlert` that was created with `alertWithMessageText:defaultButton:alternateButton:otherButton:informativeTextW‌​ithFormat:` then your switch should actually contain `NSAlertDefaultReturn` and `NSAlertAlternateReturn`.  (If it was created in any other way then your original `switch` values are correct.)